# Magento 2.2.4 blank body tag except home page and on all other pages

Tags: magento2, redirect, magento2.2.4, server-setup, white-screen

I've Magento 2.2.4. I already have files on bitbucket. I downloaded files of app/code modules and merged with fresh Magento 2.2.4 and imported the database which already exists. After running composer install, composer update, module upgrade, static content deployment, compilation, and cache refresh commands, the home page works fine but the all other pages like category page, cms pages are having a white screen and body tag with no content. When I try to navigate admin it shows too many redirects error.
I'm using wamp server on local.

Answer (score 0):

Please clear generated folder:

You can do it by below command:

> rm -rf generated/*

Please also clear cache and page-cache

> rm -rf var/cache/*   and rm -rf var/page-cache/*

check after flushing cache it ill be work

Comment: Yes. Tried this commands also.

Comment: Still not working?

Comment: Have you reindex? @BhavinShah

Comment: Yes. I did everything as mentioned in my description. I'm using Windows  wamp